# Can't start gui in Ubuntu after run 'shutdown -r now'

Tags: shutdown

After I run `sudo shutdown -r now` to restart Ubuntu, it can't automatically start the gui. But I can still login in the command line. This is the first time I come across this problem. I have used `sudo shutdown -r now` for many times before. When I try to start gui `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start`. It stop here. 
[image]

And in `/etc/default/grub`

[image]

I don't know whether `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` means it will start gui automatically

And in the command line, it seems that it's tring to start nginx and postgresql automatically and stop here.
`* starting postgresql 9.1 database server
startging nginx: nginx.
speech-dispather disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
saned disabled; edit /etc/defaultned
*checking battery state`
I don't know if it has something to with my problem.

And my Ubuntu is installed in vmware.

What happen here?

Comment: did you try `startx`?

Comment: did you recently install `gnome-shell`? It may install `gdm` with it and that can be a cause.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have tried it. Bui it can't work and give the following error messages. `Caught signal 11(segmentation fault). Server aborting
Please consult the The X.org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help
Please also check the log file at "ar/log/xorg.0.log"for addtional information.
ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
Xinit: Server error` I install postgresql yesterday, maybe it have something to do with it.

Comment: Please post the X log file cited in the error message you put in the comment. X server can't start - this is way you do not have a graphic login. In that file you should find why.

Comment: @Rmano Here are the last few lines `/lib/i386-linux-gnubd1.so.2(dlopen+0x47)
/usrb/xorg/modules/extensionsbglx.so
/usrb/xorg/modules/extensionsbglx.so
/usr/bin/X (InitExtension+0x95)
/usr/bin/X (0xb75f0000+ox255d9)
Segmentation fault at address oxc193303c... `